# R: Counting rows with similar values

Tags: r, performance, processing-efficiency

I have a data table with two columns. For each column, I want to count the number of rows with the same value for row 1 and a row 2 value that is +/- 10 of it's value for column 2. Here is an example of what some data and the result may look like:

```
Table: info
C1     C2       near
a      5        0
a      25       1
a      27       1
b      8        1
b      12       2
b      20       1
c      10       0
```

I've written an ugly for loop that does this calculation (see below), but I'm wondering if anyone has a more efficient solution that would work better on 100k+ row tables.

```
for (f in 1:5) {
  n <- info$C2[f]
  info$near[f] <- nrow(subset(info, info$C1 == info$C1[f] & info$C2 >= n-10 & info$C2 <= n+10))-1
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you elaborate your question

Comment: I'm looking for a more efficient way to calculate the "near" column than the for-loop (which works fine for small samples, but not for larger ones)

Comment: Could you update with a more general example.

Comment: I'm not sure what a more general example would look like, although I have added several additional rows to example table. 

I think the easiest way to understand the problem is by looking at the for loop which works, and thinking how to accomplish the same problem more efficiently

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
info %>% group_by(C1) %>% mutate(near = abs(diff(C2)) < 10)
```

This assumes that each value of `C1` has 2 rows.

Comment: And if values of C1 differ in the number of rows?

Comment: Then I'm not 100% sure what you want, but `near = sum(abs(diff(C2)) < 10)` might be it. (Other code being the same.)

Answer (score 0):

A more general version of the solution provided by @Gregor:

```
library(dplyr)
info %>% 
  group_by(C1) %>% 
  mutate(near = colSums(abs(outer(C2, C2, "-")) <= 10) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I quit understand your question, by it seem to me that you can achieve good performance with sqldf library. It isn't the smartest way. But it will work well.

If you want look this page https://www.google.com.br/amp/s/www.r-bloggers.com/make-r-speak-sql-with-sqldf/amp/

Comment: This would be a good answer if you gave sample code of how to do it with `sqldf`. Without that, it's not really an answer, just a comment.